Cannot pass "By" locator for List<WebElement> object
I have a list of web elements that store "price offers" and "price range" web elements. I store them into a @FindBy List locators.
Problem comes when i want to use them - I have a method that checks the price type of a product in the page - if it's a range ("..."$9.00 - $15.00"...") returns priceRange, but if it's offers ("...2 offers from...") returns priceOffers. This method requires "By" locator, it does not accept List. If i change it from List to By, the value of the locators becomes null (found in debug) and if i try to cast it inside the price type checking method, the execution fails and thread stops.
I need to iterate through each product and its price, reviews, name, stars and rating. The end goal is to store the information in an Excel sheet.
I have one working method where it stores everything (the code stores all those elements into List<> and then iterates through each element to write it in the Excel sheet), but this way each element is not related to its main product - if one product doesn't have reviews for example, in the Excel sheet this product might receive the review number of a previous (or next) product because the code doesn't store information for each individual product, but for each List<> of product elements.
The web page is "Amazon Movers & Shakers", the method and locators are as follows:
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(), 'offer from') or contains(text(), 'offers from')]")
    List<WebElement> priceOffers;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(@class, 'a-size-base a-color-price')]")
    List<WebElement> priceRange;

public boolean priceType(WebElement product) {
        try {
            WebElement offersElement = product.findElement(priceOffers);
            return offersElement.isDisplayed();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            try {
                WebElement rangeElement = product.findElement(priceRange);
                return rangeElement.isDisplayed();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


seems like you want to use product.findElements(By by)  That would return a List that meets the by condition given.  Don't use @FindBy for that since it's dependent on another webelement.  Instead of catching NoSuchElement, you'd check the WebElement array size.  If it's 0, then it didn't find any elements that match the By.  If it's >0 then iterate and do what you want with those references.
